# Select specific content from mysql database with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to echo text from a specific ID in my table..
If i use

```
<?php 
    database_connect();
    $navquery = "SELECT * from content
          WHERE id = 1
          ORDER by position;";

    $navresult = mysql_query($navquery);    
?>
```

it will echo the text in ID 1..

but when i try

```
<?php 
    database_connect();
    $navquery = "SELECT * from content
          WHERE id = 2
          ORDER by position;";

    $navresult = mysql_query($navquery);    
?>
```

it wont echo the text in ID 2..
help me please?

Comment: Have you tried the query that doesn't work from MySQL Workbench or PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: To @alex's point (+1), your code is sound (albeit you don't need to order by anything if you're only getting one row), given assumptions about your DB.  The issue seems at first glance to be that you really don't have an ID #2.  Can you just do a mysql dump and post that?

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a row on your content table with an id of 2.  You can try the query below to get another row.

```
SELECT * 
FROM content
WHERE ID<>1
LIMIT 1
```